# Determine if a field from one table is like the field from another table and if so count occurrence and if less than 3 return the name

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables images and Interactions in the same DB.  I want to determine if the image.images which has a png file name for example
1001_A01_1-4_5mM_3AT_Xgal_7d_W.cropped.resized.grey.png is like plate_name.Interactions which would look like 1001_A01 and then count how many times the images show up.  I should get 3 images if there are fewer than 3 images I would like to have plate_name.Interactions returned.    I would like to do this using 1 query.

So far I have just tried to count how many occurrences there are but this is failing:

```
select plate_name.Interactions, count(*) as count from Interactions where plate_name.Interactions like image.images;
```

Here are the tables in question:

```
mysql> desc images;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| image      | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| user_id    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| project_id | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc Interactions;
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| plate_name           | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| plate_number         | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| bait_sequence_name   | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| bait_gene_promoter   | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| array_coord          | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| transcriptor_factor  | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| orf_name             | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| y_coord              | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| x_coord              | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| orig_intensity_value | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rc_intensity_value   | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ptp_intensity_value  | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| z_score              | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| z_prime              | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| call_type            | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| bleed_over           | varchar(25) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| plate_median         | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| bait_gene            | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| bait_prey_orf        | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| human_call           | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modified_call        | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| duplicate_call       | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_id              | varchar(25) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| project_id           | varchar(25) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Added in response to Bobby's answer:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+---    ---+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+---    ---+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | images       | index | NULL          | image        | 208     | NULL |   19581 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Interactions | range | plate_median  | plate_median | 5       |   NULL | 3714984 | Using where; Using join buffer                            |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: so, do you want do it in one query or several query?
and your query has a "," after count, that will make an error

Comment: @BobbyStenly thanks I updated the question I would like to be able to do this using only 1 query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you write your table name and your column name in incorrect format..
if I'm right, the query should return only plate_name which it has less than 3 images, 
so you can do it with a GROUP BY and HAVING method..

```
SELECT Iteractions.plate_name, count(*) as `count`
FROM Interactions, Images
WHERE Interactions.plate_name LIKE Images.image
GROUP BY Interactions.plate_name
HAVING count(*) < 3
```

Please try that, and tell me if that's not what you want.. :)

Comment: Hi Bobby I think that the response might be fine but the query is not finishing I did an explain on it I will update the answer with the results of the explain if you have any ideas on how I might improve this that would be great!